# How to create new group in alfresco cmis or apache cmis through java?

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new in alfresco, and Any how I have to use alfresco cmis through java. Now I want to create new group in alfresco cmis through java.

For this i have found one link about groups that is shown below.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/RESTful-Groups.html

I got one rest full link that is shown below

```
POST /alfresco/service/api/groups/{shortName}/children/{fullAuthorityName}
```

But here I am not understanding how to create group.

Please any body help me......

Comment: please see this link and give me a feedback https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference

Comment: Check this fourm https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/create-user-and-group-cmis-07202013-0731

Comment: I used it and it's worked fine just use Postman to give a little try to this Restful Request

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use CMIS to create groups because the [CMIS specification](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/cmis/) does not cover users or groups.

Comment: Would you please tell me ,What are the specifications of CMIS?